# Переиспользование переменной в запросе Postman

Tags: json, переменные, postman

Новичок в постмане. Пожалуйста, помогите понять, что делаю не так. Ковыряю популярный тренажер https://petstore.swagger.io/#/
В пре-реквесте коллекции задала рандомайзер, который генерирует айдишник:

```
pm.collectionVariables.set('randomNumber', Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000000000000));
```

В хендлере pet взяла метод POST - создание пета, где в боди подставила переменную с рандомным айдишником:

```
{
  "id": {{randomNumber}},
  "category": {
    "id": 0,
    "name": "string"
  },
  "name": "Basil",
  "photoUrls": [
    "string"
  ],
  "tags": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "name": "string"
    }
  ],
  "status": "available"
}
```

Затем в этом запросе во вкладке "тесты" я загоняю полученый в ответе айдишник в переменную:

```
var data = JSON.parse(responseBody);
pm.collectionVariables.set("petId", data.id);
```

Затем в следующем тесте POST - Upload Image я хочу взять эту переменную с полученным айдишником и загрузить ему изображение (form-data), отправляю запрос, а в curl появляется вообще левый айдишник:

```
curl --location 'https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/pet/9223372036854753000/uploadImage' \
--form 'file=@"photo_2023-05-30_14-13-58.jpg"' \
--form 'id="9223372036854753000"'
```

Есть ощущение, что в запрос POST - Upload Image не подтягивается переменная petId. Что не так?

Answer (score 0):

в js тип number максимальное число 9007199254740991 (16 знаков)

предположу что из-за этого

попробуй в BigInt положить
https://learn.javascript.ru/types

или в строку преобразуй

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась переименованием переменной с petId на currentId +  в этом скрипте

```
var data = JSON.parse(responseBody);
pm.collectionVariables.set("petId", data.id);
```

замена двойных кавычек на одинарные.
Что-то из этого помогло.
Ну, и в рандомайзер добавила это число:
9007199254740991